# Ice cream&cone combinatorics question

Tags: probability, combinations

There are 31 flavours of ice cream and 3 different choices of ice cream cones.
How many possible two-scoop ice cream and cone possibilities are there? Consider that a combination of a scoop of vanilla followed by a scoop of chocolate is the same as a scoop of chocolate followed by a scoop of vanilla.

I know how to calculate 31 flavours of ice cream with two-scoop, but I couldn't figure it out with 3 different ice cream cones.

Comment: Just multiply the number of different two-scoop combinations by $3$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need a combination of scoops, AND a choice of cone.

The number of ways in which you can do this in $\displaystyle \binom{31}{2}+31$, the number of ways to choose two scoops, times $3$, the number of ways to choose a cone.